# Taylor expansion of the first 3 non-zero terms of sinh(x) about x=a

Tags: taylor-expansion

For the Taylor expansion of the first three non-zero terms of $\sinh(x)$ about $x=a$, can this be done?

The reason I am a bit confused is that there are an infinite number of $(x-a)^n$ terms which then contribute to the linear/quadratic terms.

Answer (score 1):

To obtain the Taylor expansion, one  way is to use the hyperbolic trigonometric formula
$$\sinh(a + (x-a)) = \sinh a \cosh (x-a) + \cosh a \sinh (x-a)$$ and to use Taylor expansions at order $3$ at zero of $\sinh h$ and $\cosh h$ where $h = x-a$

An alternate way is to use the formula:

$$f(x-a) = f(a) + f^\prime(a) \frac{(x-a)^1}{1!} + f^{\prime\prime}(a) \frac{(x-a)^2}{2!} +f^{(3)}(a) \frac{(x-a)^3}{3!} + o(x-a)^3.$$

In any case, the terms $(x-a)^n$ with $n \ge 3$ won't contribute to the linear and quadratic terms.

Comment: Thanks for your answer - one thing which I am still unclear about is: why does n =3 not contribute to linear cases? The expansion of (x-a)^3 is x^3 - 3ax^2 + 3a^2x - a^3 which has linear and quadratic contributions. For the question of "find the first 3 non-zero terms", would this not need to be taken into consideration?

Comment: When you do the expansion around $a$, you are expecting terms of the form $(x-a)^n$. So don't perform the expansion of polynomials as you mention.